# MySQL .NET data provider doesn't appear in results from GetFactoryClasses

Tags: mysql, .net

An application developed with VS 2010 and .NET 4, originally and successfully deployed on Vista, after installing on Windows 8.1 has exhibited the following problem (after installing the official MySQL data provider version 5.0.9):

A call to DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses returns all the other providers (ODBC, SQL Server, etc.), but not the MySQL provider.

What could be wrong? Is the version not compatible with 8.1? Does the installer not register it so that DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses can find it? Could there be a 64 vs 32 bit issue?